# Custom Taghelper doesn't work in viewcoponent's View page

Tags: dll, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I was using .Net core 2.1 as develp eviroment.
I have create a libray project that includes ViewComponents and Custom TagHelpers,some ViewComponent's view page(.cshtml file).
And then I create a MVC,
Source code is in [here](https://github.com/Kiakaa/TagHelperInViewComponentNotWork).

Comment: new link is here:https://github.com/Kiakaa/ViewComponentWithTagHelper

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular, post the code in your question, not as a link. In doing so post only the code necessary to reproduce what's happening, i.e. your tag helper and view component class and view.